# How can i get browser history from google chrome in node on windows?

Tags: javascript, c#, node.js, windows, google-chrome

I'm creating the lifestyle electron app for myself.
And one of the features is control my daily browser surfing through internet.
I'm trying to bring my chrome history to electron app.

Is there any *cheap* version of getting this and don't use any c++ or c# with implementation only using node?

Comment: Have you seen the [Node Browser History Package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-browser-history)?

Comment: @Snel23. Yeap, i getting errors on install. Here they are: https://pastebin.com/aEPvBHLQ

Comment: Looks like sqlite3 is failing to install. Maybe [this thread](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/issues/972) might help?

Comment: @Snel23. After swithing to another branch that works! Thx!

Answer (score 0):

After switch this module to fork https://github.com/G0BL1N/node-browser-history/
That works. Module still have some problems with Windows, but it can do it's job

Comment: Btw, this module on windows works not good at all.
But it's rather small and you can create this by yourself.
Main goal is to get history file and open it with your sqlite